# Can this package be recompiled

Tags: module, compilation, nginx, yum

Hello I asked this question to superuser but I did not get a good question there and i really need the answer. I know some of you here can answer this question.

I have installed nginx via yum. Now I want to add a module, but I have to compile the source again and include the the new module.

But i can't find the source. Does someone know what I have to do to recompile the source and get the module in.

> ### Update

I did everything in the answer from Patrick and it worked out great. However when now when I run the yum update it wants to update the installed rpm with the same version.

Can I just let it update, or should i specify that it is already up to date.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Redhat and related distributions (fedora, centos) keep their source rpms in a highly regular directory tree. for RHEL5 you want: ftp://ftp.redhat.com/pub/redhat/linux/enterprise/5Server/en/os/SRPMS/ for other releases, you can browse the ftp server until you find what you want. Otherwise, google for the exact version of nginx you have (`rpm -q nginx`)

Assuming you can find the srpm, install it with rpm:

```
rpm -ivh nginx-xxxx.src.rpm
```

This'll put the sources and build files in `/usr/src/redhat/{BUILD,SPEC,SRC,SOURCES}`. You can modify the `.spec` file in `/usr/src/redhat/SPEC` to build the module you want along with the rest of nginx, or you can build nginx manually.

Which module do you want to build? In [fedora's nginx.spec](http://cvs.fedoraproject.org/viewvc/rpms/nginx/EL-5/nginx.spec?view=markup), several modules are specified when `configure` is run. This may be as simple as adding a line here:

```
./configure \
[snip...]
--with-http_realip_module \
--with-http_addition_module \
--with-http_sub_module \
--with-http_dav_module \
--with-http_flv_module \
--with-http_gzip_static_module \
--with-http_stub_status_module \
--with-http_perl_module \
[snip...]
```

After adding whatever changes to `nginx.spec`, you can build the final `rpm` with `rpmbuild`:

```
rpmbuild -ba nginx.spec
```

Assuming the package builds without error, rpmbuild will leave it in    `/usr/src/redhat/RPMS/`

**Update:** yum will want to replace your nginx package as updates become available. You will probably want to rebuild each new package as it becomes available, using the same process as above. **However,** If security is not a concern, you can simple exclude nginx from the update list by adding the following to your yum config (probably `/etc/yum.repos.d/${repo}.repo` or similar. **Be sure to associate it with the right repo**):

```
exclude=nginx*
```

Or running yum with the --exclude option

```
yum --exclude=nginx*
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have found the rpm. I tried rpm -ivh nginx-xxxx.src.rpm but this just installs the file without leaving any traces behind.

Comment: what does "rpm2cpio nginx-xxx.src.rpm | cpio --list" give you? You can also unpack the package manually with "rpm2cpio nginx-xxx.rpm | cpio -ivd"

Comment: Yes i found the problem, I did not get the src package but the compiled one. Now the files go in the right directories. Let me try the rebuild

Comment: Yes I think this method worked. I did not get any errors. Thank you for the nice response and your time.

Comment: Saif, I've added some discussion of what to do about updates. In brief, either get the new .src.rpm and build it, or exclude nginx from updates.